# Saving a Django form submission for later use

Tags: database, django, forms

I have a complex search form with about two dozen CharField and ChoiceFields.

My users want to be able to save specific queries (giving each one a name) so they can run them routinely without choosing all of the fields manually.

Should I just pickle the form object and save it in the datbase?

EDIT: I should note that they want to be able to modify the form choices after the fact as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the form itself, but the value returned from the `cleaned_data` attribute.

Comment: This is a good idea, for security. Would this allow me to show the saved form again with the fields already selected?

Comment: [Yes.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial)